# Algorithm to search tree-like structured relational data (use example: elasticsearch)

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch, search, data-structures

**Question 1:**
I have a tree-like data structure to search items, e.g.,

```
living creatures
      /  \
    bird  fish
    / \    / \
canary Penguin
```

I am looking for a way to switch on/off the search results. For example, if bird is disabled, when a search is performed against the term "bird", bird and its children should not be appeared in the results.  If bird is enabled, when the term "bird" is searched, bird (or bird and its children) should be appeared.

**Question 2**
Right now, I am putting this tree structure as a flatten list in the Elastic search as a field, what is the best way to make it a tree strucutre (I know I can use a nested fields but considering we have 30 levels depth and 100,000 children and most documents only have a few children.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Nesting is preferable if cardinality is low. In your case cardinality is high and level of nesting is also high. Updating a nested doc will cause indexing of containing doc. I do think that the way you are currently maintaining is good. What problems are u facing with current state?

Answer (score 0):

You needn't use nesting in this case, you can use your flatten list, make the field at lowest level as your index/primary key and each of its parent as a field, so your entries will become

```
"canary":{
    "l1":"living creatures",
    "l2":"carnivore",
    "l3":"bird",
}
"dolphin":{
    "l1":"living creatures",
    "l2":"fish",
}
"Penguin":{
    "l1":"living creatures",
    "l2":"fish, bird",
    "##assuming penguin is both
}
```

Then when u need to disable the entry, you can simply disable any document that has bird in it, of course data is repeated but that's noSQL

Comment: What about the use case where field on l2 is disabled but still l1 should be searchable ?

Comment: Each searchable field should have a seperate entry, so {l1:living creatures} if it's searchable will be a sperate entry/document in the index

Comment: That means every node will have an entry Containing its parent level details correct?

Comment: No, However each node can have an entry similar to another document parent field in case u want to search a parent field but unlike relational db these are totally independent

Comment: Thanks for the comments @AdityaAgarwal. The problem I have with flatten the list is that we have 100k vocabularies in a tree structure ( I have yet to check the maximum depth of the tree, but wont be a small number 30+). As a result, it will end up with a huge document.

Comment: As we all know ES is very scalable, it can easily work with 100k+ documents, only thing u need to worry about is the hardware requirements

Comment: Also I think if u use tree structure, then u need to check more than one document/row while fetching something, that will greatly increase your search latency